# Simple way to specify a pass a style with syntax `my style={foo}`

Tags: tikz-pgf

I’d like to provide an interface like:

```
\myNode{content=My content, style node={fill=red}}
```

While it is easy to provide an interface where we use `style node/.style={}`, I struggle to find an elegant way to specify style this way, especially if I define inside functions with arguments. I found a solution, but it is quite complex, involve a second dummy style and expl3… so I guess I’m missing something obvious. Is there a simpler solution?

Ideally, I’d like to be able to say that `style node={…}` is like `style node/.style={}`.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[options]{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\begin{document}

\ExplSyntaxOn
% Otherwise I need to double the number of hashes

\cs_generate_variant:Nn \str_replace_all:Nnn { Nnx }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \tl_rescan:nn { nv }

\cs_set:Nn \str_set_double_hash_robust:Nn {
  \str_set:Nn {#1} {#2}
  \str_replace_all:Nnx {#1} { #### } { \c_hash_str }
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\robExtRescanDoubleHashRobust}{m}{
  \str_set_double_hash_robust:Nn \l_robExt_tmp_str {#1}
  \tl_rescan:nv {}{ l_robExt_tmp_str }
}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\makeatletter
\NewDocumentCommand{\myNode}{m}{
  \pgfkeys{
    /test/.cd,
    content node/.store in=\myContent,
    content node=Default,
    style node aux/.style={},
    style node/.code={%
      \robExtRescanDoubleHashRobust{%
        \pgfkeysalso{%
          /test/style node aux/.style={##1}%
        }%
      }
    },%
    % /test/style node aux/.style={##1}},%
    #1,
  }
  \node[draw, /test/style node aux]{\myContent};
}
\makeatother

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \myNode{
    content node=Yes,
    style node={
      rounded corners,
      draw,
      test/.style={fill=#1},
      test=red,
    }
  }
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Off-topic: you shouldn't use `\cs_set:Nn \str_set_double_hash_robust:Nn` for two reasons. First, `set` overwrites an existing function without raising an error. You shouldn't use it unless you previously created the function. Second, the name should begin with a private or package-specific prefix. It shouldn't use the prefix of an existing module (`str`), especially not a kernel module. (And if the function is only for internal use, it should begin with two underscores.)

Comment: Also `\str_set:Nn {#1} {#2}` should be `\str_set:Nn #1 {#2}`. Similarly elsewhere. `N` expects e.g. a variable name.

Comment: @cfr good to know, thanks!

Comment: You say you want it to behave like the `.style` case, but you'd have to double hashes there, too, wouldn't you? Have you considered just using `.code`? Also, it would be more efficient and avoid some of the doubling to define the keys independently, rather than every time you use `\myNode`.

Comment: @cfr Let’s that I want it to behave like a `.style` without arguments ^^ I managed to get something using `apply style/.code={\tikzset{/tikz/.cd,#1}}`, and `apply style/.expand` and it worked for me in a more complicated setup where I need to put the style in a global variable that I receive somewhere else (not sure why it fails on this MWE, I guess it is because I don't use a variable here).

Comment: @cfr Regarding the efficiency, I’d love to find a cleaner way to do that: do you mean to define them in `\pgfkeys{…}` outside the node and then just do a `/test/.cd` in the pgfkeys, together will calling the keys to reset their values?

Comment: Does that mean that `style node={…}` defines a style while `style node` (without a parameter) should execute a style?

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel yes. Ideally, I could also do `style node/.append style` if I prefer to add to style instead of replacing it.

Comment: Opinion incoming: I have to say, I don't like it. I don't often use it but the PGFPlots package has too many styles as well that set other styles. In my opinion, a good approach ist to user a `every <sth>` style (like `every node`) and then use `<sth>s/.style={every <sth>/.append style={#1}}` (like `nodes`), i.e. the plural without the *every*, to append to it. Everything else is messy. Let the user learn a bit PGFKeys, it's worth it.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel The thing it that not only it is longer to type, but I also often get mysterious errors because I just forgot a `/.style`, and the messages are often quite unclear and hard to debug. Regarding the convention, it is nice and this is indeed not the first time I see this convention, thanks. But regarding the name, in my case I have a single node that the style should be apply to, so `every …` does not make much sense, do you know of a similar convention for single nodes? Or maybe `main node={}` vs `main node style/.style={}`?And I guess I need `estyle/unexpanded` to avoid doubling #

Comment: PGFPlots seems to roughly `<sthy> style/.style={(every) <sty>/.append style={#1}}`. [More or less.](https://tikz.dev/pgfplots/reference-styleoptions#pgfp./pgfplots/every:axis:label). In the linked set of styles the `axis` that's present in the `every axis label` key is suddenly gone with `label style` and `xlabel style` and `x label style` (that these two exist at the same time is already ... oof). The same with seemingly every other *every* style in this long list. But the appenders for the axis line styles keep the `axis` in the name. It's just too much variations and alternatives imo.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel Thanks. Ahah, I personally don't mind having multiple alias for the same thing (of course I expect `xlabel` and `x label` to do the same thing), as I don't need to remember "is there a space or not?", as both would work :-P And sometimes it is needed to have both backward compatible code and unified interface.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest solution, if your `style node aux` shouldn't take any arguments itself, is to use the `.estyle` handler instead of `.style` to set it up, and nest an `\unexpanded`:

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\begin{document}

\makeatletter
\pgfkeys{
  /test/.cd,
  content node/.store in=\myContent,
  style node/.code = {%
    \pgfkeysalso{/test/style node aux/.estyle=\unexpanded{#1}}%
  },
% a .style is internally a .code with `\pgfkeysalso{<stuff>}`. 
% a .code is set up using `\pgfkeysdef{\pgfkeyscurrentpath}{#1}`
% and `\pgfkeysdef` sets up an internal value in `\pgfkeyscurrentpath/.@body`
% Unfortunately the developers of `pgfkeys` decided that the `.@body` of an
% `estyle` should also get the expanded tokens, which makes it much harder
% adding to it in a generic way (provided that the adding is also done with an
% `\edef`). I have no idea what should be easier with this behaviour, but it
% is what it is. The result is, that the following is not a generic `.eappend
% style`, but works for our `style node`.
  addstyle node/.code = {%
    \begingroup
      \pgfkeysgetvalue{/test/style node aux/.@body}\mytmp
      \ifx\mytmp\relax
        \PackageError{my-pgfkeys-extension}{Not a style: \pgfkeysgetvalue}{}%
        \let\mytmp\empty
      \fi
      \def\mytmpB##1%
        {%
          \endgroup
          \pgfkeysedef{/test/style node aux}
            {\unexpanded{##1}\noexpand\pgfkeysalso{\unexpanded{#1}}}%
        }%
    \expandafter\mytmpB\expandafter{\mytmp}%
  },
}
\NewDocumentCommand{\myNode}{m}{
  \pgfkeys{
    /test/.cd,
    content node=Default,
    style node aux/.style={},%
    #1%
  }
  \node[draw, /test/style node aux]{\myContent};
}
\makeatother

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \myNode{
    content node=Yes,
    style node={
      test/.style={fill=#1},
      test=red,
    },
    addstyle node={rounded corners}
  }
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

---

The following is a simpler version of above's code for `addstyle node`. This works by keeping the definition in a separate data container instead of using `pgfkeys`' data storage (because then we have total control over our data storage and can reuse it).

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\begin{document}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*\test@stylenode{}
\pgfkeys{
  /test/.cd,
  content node/.store in=\myContent,
  style node/.code = {%
    \edef\test@stylenode{\unexpanded{#1}}%
    \pgfkeysalso{/test/style node aux/.estyle=\unexpanded{#1}}%
  },
  addstyle node/.code = {%
    \edef\test@stylenode{\unexpanded\expandafter{\test@stylenode,#1}}%
    \pgfkeysalso{/test/style node aux/.estyle=\unexpanded\expandafter{\test@stylenode}}%
  },
}
\NewDocumentCommand{\myNode}{m}{
  \pgfkeys{
    /test/.cd,
    content node=Default,
    style node aux/.style={},%
    #1%
  }
  \node[draw, /test/style node aux]{\myContent};
}
\makeatother

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \myNode{
    content node=Yes,
    style node={
      test/.style={fill=#1},
      test=red,
    },
    addstyle node={rounded corners}
  }
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Definitely better than mine.

Comment: Oh really cool magic, thanks!

Comment: @tobiasBora this magic is basically what `expl3` does for its `\tl_set:Nn` in order to be able to store `#` without doubling. `\tl_set:Nn` is (excluding some checks): `\edef#1{\unexpanded{#2}}`, and that's a faster variant of the pre-e-TeX trick `\toks0={#2}\edef#1{\the\toks0}` (`\unexpanded` is basically an expandable way of storing something in a `toks` register and reinserting the result of `\the\toks`).

Comment: Cool, thanks a lot, easier than playing with replace in string!

Comment: I wanted to do it for `.append estyle` instead of `.estyle`, but it turns out that this function does not exist… Do you have an equivalent solution when I want to append to the style?

Comment: @tobiasBora you're leaving documented features with that, so in theory a solution working for that might break with future versions of `pgfkeys` (though that's unlikely to happen). Still interested?

Comment: @Skillmon What do you mean? But yeah, I’m interested! (but is it how tikz defines stuff like `every node`?)

Comment: @tobiasBora no, but you'll need to directly access the macros internally used to store a `style`.

Comment: Hum interesting. It it equivalent to redefining a `.append estyle` that I can reuse later?

Comment: @tobiasBora I edited my answer to also include an `addstyle node` key.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Seems like the solution of @cfr `/zx/boxes/.code={\scantokens{\pgfkeysalso{/zx/every box/.append style={#1}}}},` is simpler to add to a style, and yours is simpler to set a style, but good to have different approaches ^^ Thanks a lot!

Comment: @tobiasBora I'd stay away from `\scantokens` if it's not absolutely necessary to use it. `\scantokens` is a rather complicated primitive. In the usage by @cfr it creates a stray space for instance (which just doesn't hurt because you're using it inside of a `tikzpicture`). I'll provide alternative code that doesn't have such problems.

Comment: @Skillmon oh interesting, that is good to know! Is this also applying to the expl3 version? I submitted an issue here for reference https://github.com/pgf-tikz/pgf/issues/1283

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if this fulfils your desiderata, because I'm not clear about all the factors involved (or *where* precisely you want to avoid doubling hashes).

The following uses a reduced version of `expl3`. I'm not convinced rescanning tokens is the best approach here, but it seems to work in minimal test cases.

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\ExplSyntaxOn
% Otherwise I need to double the number of hashes

\NewDocumentCommand{\robExtRescanDoubleHashRobust}{m}{
  \tl_rescan:nn {} {#1}
}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\pgfqkeys{/test}{%
  content node/.store in=\myContent,
  content node=Default,
  style node aux/.style={},
  style node/.code={%
    \robExtRescanDoubleHashRobust{%
      \pgfqkeysalso{/test}{%
        style node aux/.style={#1}%
      }%
    }
  },
  /test/.code={%
    \pgfkeys{/test/.cd,#1}%
  },
  /test/.search also={/tikz,/pgf},% usually a good idea
}
\NewDocumentCommand{\myNode}{m}{%
  \begingroup
    \pgfkeys{%
      /test={#1},
    }
    \node[draw, /test/style node aux]{\myContent};
  \endgroup
}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \myNode{}
  \myNode{%
    yshift=10mm,
    content node=Yes,
    style node={%
      rounded corners,
      draw,
      test/.style={fill=#1},
      test=red,
    }
  }
  \scoped[yshift=20mm]{\myNode{}}
  \myNode{%
    content node=no,
    style node={test/.style={fill=#1},test=green,double,font=\bfseries},
    yshift=30mm,
  }
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\ExplSyntaxOn
% Otherwise I need to double the number of hashes

\NewDocumentCommand{\robExtRescanDoubleHashRobust}{m}{
  \tl_rescan:nn {} {#1}
}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\pgfqkeys{/test}{%
  content node/.store in=\myContent,
  content node=Default,
  style node aux/.style={},
  style node/.code={%
    \robExtRescanDoubleHashRobust{%
      \pgfqkeysalso{/test}{%
        style node aux/.style={#1}%
      }%
    }
  },
  /test/.code={%
    \pgfkeys{/test/.cd,#1}%
  },
  /test/.search also={/tikz,/pgf},% usually a good idea
}
\NewDocumentCommand{\myNode}{m}{%
  \begingroup
    \pgfkeys{%
      /test={#1},
    }
    \node[draw, /test/style node aux]{\myContent};
  \endgroup
}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \myNode{}
  \myNode{%
    yshift=10mm,
    content node=Yes,
    style node={%
      rounded corners,
      draw,
      test/.style={fill=#1},
      test=red,
    }
  }
  \scoped[yshift=20mm]{\myNode{}}
  \myNode{%
    content node=no,
    style node={test/.style={fill=#1},test=green,double,font=\bfseries},
    yshift=30mm,
  }
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Alternatively, you could use a TeX primitive instead of the `expl3`.

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\pgfqkeys{/test}{%
  content node/.store in=\myContent,
  content node=Default,
  style node aux/.style={},
  style node/.code={%
    \scantokens{%
      \pgfqkeysalso{/test}{%
        style node aux/.style={#1}%
      }%
    }
  },
  /test/.code={%
    \pgfkeys{/test/.cd,#1}%
  },
  /test/.search also={/tikz,/pgf},% usually a good idea
}
\NewDocumentCommand{\myNode}{m}{%
  \begingroup
    \pgfkeys{%
      /test={#1},
    }
    \node[draw, /test/style node aux]{\myContent};
  \endgroup
}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \myNode{}
  \myNode{%
    yshift=10mm,
    content node=Yes,
    style node={%
      rounded corners,
      draw,
      test/.style={fill=#1},
      test=red,
    }
  }
  \scoped[yshift=20mm]{\myNode{}}
  \myNode{%
    content node=no,
    style node={test/.style={fill=#1},test=green,double,font=\bfseries},
    yshift=30mm,
  }
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

The output is the same in both cases:
[image: output from either code block]

Comment: Thanks a lot! I hoped a simpler solution exist without using two styles, but it is good enough for my need and thanks for the nice example on how to clean styles!

Comment: @tobiasBora I've tended to find it's not worth the effort. In cases where I've done something similar (though not quite like this), using the second style tends to make the solution cleaner overall and more robust. It also makes it easy to create a third style which adds to the default rather than replacing it, so you can make a group or pair of styles. E.g. `style node+` adds `style node'` replaces and `style node` adds or replaces, depending on what makes sense as a default.

Answer (score 0):

Here are two solutions. They don't have the exact syntax you want but I hope they will be useful.

One solution is to use `\tikzstyle` to define custom styles.

```
\tikzstyle{mynode} = [draw, fill=red]

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw (0, 0) node[mynode, ...](A){Yes};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Another solution is to use `\newcommand` to define [macros](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Macros).

```
\newcommand{\mynode}[2]{
  node[#1](){#2}
}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw (0, 0) \mynode{draw, fill=red}{Yes};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: The `\tikzstyle` macro is deprecated, you should use `\tikzset` instead

Comment: Thanks, but sadly it is not the syntax I wanted. In my case I have multiple nodes that I want to address separately without playing with arguments (and actually it is even more complicated since I need to put the result in a global macro to teleport it outside of the current group to another part of the picture…). Funnily enough I found a syntax that works in my application but not on this MWE using `zx apply style/.code={\tikzset{/tikz/.cd,#1}},` and `zx apply style/.expand`.